# C# Color constant R,G,B values

Tags: c#, colors, rgb, system.drawing.color

Where can I find a list of all the C# Color constants and the associated R,G,B (Red, Green, Blue) values?

e.g.

Color.White == (255,255,255)

Color.Black == (0,0,0)

etc...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Run this program:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var props = typeof(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            Color color = (Color) prop.GetValue(null, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Color.{0} = ({1}, {2}, {3})", prop.Name,
                              color.R, color.G, color.B);
        }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (KnownColor known in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
        {
            Color color = Color.FromKnownColor(known);
            Console.WriteLine("Color.{0} = ({1}, {2}, {3})", known,
                              color.R, color.G, color.B);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'd prefer to use the first one because using KnownColor adds the color of the controls and windows in the system.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like this [page](http://www.flounder.com/csharp_color_table.htm) has all of them.

Answer (score 5):

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx)

[Colors by name/hex via MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358802.aspx)