# Is there a way to see the color that will display for a .NET color name?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, colors, color-scheme, color-picker

I'm using System.Drawing.Color, is there anything in Visual Studio that can display the color for the name?

For example if I used `Color.Cornsilk` what would color would be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Forms properties window allows you to select Color related properties using a "Color Picker" that displays the actual color next to the name.

Just type in the color name within the property value area, press enter, and if the name is a known .NET color, it is shown.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/ZetaColorVisualizer.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could test the color on any control through VS designer.
Set a `Panel BackgroundColor` for example.

Anyway named color samples can be found anywhere on the web.
Here is a [good reference](http://www.colorexplorer.com/colorlibraries.aspx) for working with colors (select `Named Web Color` in the drop down).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Jon Skeets Answer from this post

[C# Color constant R,G,B values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225953/c-color-constant-rgb-values)

Comment: That will get the RGB value, but the questioner wants to see the actual colour on screen in the IDE.