# C# color value from name

Tags: c#, enums, colors

I need to get the RGB value of a color given it's name in C#. I am trying to use the predefined KnownColors enum, but can't figure out how to get the value.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Color class has some interesting static methods:

```
Color.FromName ("Red").ToArgb()
```

Next to that, there are some properties like:

```
var c = Color.FromName ("Red"); // Or use Color.FromKnownColor (KnownColor.Red) 

Console.WriteLine (String.Format ("RGB: {0} {1} {2}", c.R, c.G, c.B);
```

Comment: FromKnownColor makes more sense since he's said that's what he's using.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`FromKnownColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromknowncolor.aspx):

```
Color blue = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Blue);
```

Then `blue.R`, `blue.G` and `blue.B` for the RGB values.

---

Or, if you just want the `int` value for the RGB color, you can do:

```
int blueRgb = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Blue).ToArgb();
```

Comment: Toargb returns a 32 bit int, not what he wants. EDIT: i don't think.

Comment: The problem is I have the color name in a string

Comment: @baruch: in that case Frederik Gheysels's answer hits the spot :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Color.FromKnownColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromknowncolor.aspx) then access RGB values using `Color.R`, `Color.G` and `Color.B`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Color clr = FromKnownColor(System.Drawing.KnownColor.Blue);
string.Format("R:{0}, G:{1}, B:{2}" clr.R, clr.G, clr.B);
```

Check this [Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225953/c-color-constant-r-g-b-values)

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`You could do

```
  int r = Color.FromName("Purple").ToArgb();
     //Or 
     int r1 = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Purple).ToArgb();
```

Color.FromName and Color.FromKnownColor witll return Color object and it has properties for `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` components if you want that.

Answer (score -1):

```
Color c = (Color)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color)).ConvertFromString("Red");
```